# Eclipse CDT Debugging (An External Process) and Finding Its Source Code

Tags: eclipse, gcc, gdb, cygwin, eclipse-cdt

When I attempt to debug a external process with Eclipse CDT, I'm able to attach to it, but I cannot get the debug configuration to find the original C source. When I launch the debugger with the process running within Eclipse, I can get the debugger to find the source code.

It is only when attaching to an external process that CDT doesn't find it. It simply sits content with showing the disassembled code. The problem is that the process handles input from the command line, and I don't seem to find a way to launch the debugger within Eclipse CDT and allow me to enter input.

I'm using Eclipse CDT (Helios) and Cygwin 1.7.1 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your original goal is to pass arguments to the debugger (and not finding the source code, as your title implies), you can do it in Eclipse by going to `Run -> Debug Configurations` and selecting the `Arguments` tab, in which you can type the input arguments to your application.

Comment: Thanks. It was some sort of problem sync'ing Eclipse with the cygwin toolchain compounded with the fact I wasn't aware of the Debug Configuration settings you just mentioned. Thanks.