# Attaching GDB to Eclipse to debug JNI C++ code

Tags: eclipse, debugging, gdb, java-native-interface

I'm having problems debugging a JNI application. I've read several threads in StackOverflow, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2762916/how-to-use-eclipse-to-debug-jni-code-java-c-c), [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3973825/eclipse-cdt-debugging-an-external-process-and-finding-its-source-code) or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9256176/how-to-debug-java-jni-using-gdb-on-linux). I've also tried to start gdb in a separated shell and attach it to the running java process. In both cases, the problem is the same: GDB can't find the sources to debug. Things tried

- Add "dir" line to gdbinit, pointing to C++ sources folder
- Adding the C++ sources folder to the GDB debbuging configuration in Eclipse, in the "Sources" tab.
- Adding set environment LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/library.so, being library.so the library file built from C++ source files
- Attach ddd to the java process, but then I get an error because pthread_join.c is not found in the working directory. I don't have this file in my hard disk. I don't know what is this about.

Nothing worked. I've spent several days on this. I know my bug is in the C++ code called by the JNI wrapper, but I can't debug it. Any hints? If helps, I'm running Eclipse Juno in Debian 7 under a Parallels VM on Mac OS.

Many thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2):

You need to have debug information in your native library. You should pass `-g` to your compiler and linker to have this information in the executable. You may also want to add `-O0`.

Comment: Yes, I compiled it in that way. Actually, I can debug just the C++ library, using GDB/DDD, directly calling the methods I want to test. The problem arises when this library is called from a JNI wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to attaching to the Java process, you can create a C++ app and debug it directly. You just need to link in the functions you want to test. In the main function, [create the VM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/invocation.html#wp15956), register the functions with [RegisterNatives](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html#wp5833), and kick off a Java test class the uses them.

Hopefully, the debugger has no problem finding the sources since it is just part of the normal compile/link/debug loop of a C++ app.

Comment: That sounds interesting. Many thanks. But I'd like to find a way to debug the current code. It's pretty big and complex, and I'm afraid that if I lose context, I won't be able to find the bug.

Comment: This is actually a good idea. You don't change your application, you only use a native main() instead of Java main.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to start with the latest [ADT bundle](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). You can even download [the Mac version](http://dl.google.com/android/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20130522.zip), so you will not even need Parallels (see a detailed [instructions](http://blog.lbfctry.com/2013/01/01/getting-started-on-androids-adt-bundle-on-mac-osx/)). Then, choose *Debug Android Native Application* in launch menu.

Comment: Thanks for your tip. But I'm not developing on Android. I'm working with a Java Desktop application that uses a C++ library via JNI to perform some operations. I want to be able to debug both, Java and C++ parts, using Eclipse.

Comment: Oops, I missed this tiny detail ;-)

Comment: No problem. Thanks for your response, anyway :-)